# Show foreign key relation message when deleting records in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have a table Country.CountryID is a foreign key on another table Energy.When I try to delete a record in Country table,I should get a message showing the foreign key relation.
That message should also display the name of the child tables.I have used jtable.

EDIT:
Model is:-

```
public class Country
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CountryID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Country Name is required")]        
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
}

public class Energy
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int EnergyID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required.")]
        public int? CountryID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CountryID")]
        public virtual Country Countries { get; set; }
}
```

Inside controller I have written like this:-

```
SqlException sqlException = ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.InnerException as SqlException : null;
                if (sqlException != null) return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = "Sorry! unable to delete." });
                else return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
```

How to get related table names in mvc3??
Is it possible using linq??

Comment: Post the code for the models.

Comment: The question is would you like to show such a message to the user?

Comment: Try using `ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message)`

Comment: I would like to show message to user containing name of related tables.ex.Message just show "An error occured..."

Comment: Why. What is the user going to do with that? Check for link in Energy and disable delete. Worst case, message should be "Country cannot be deleted. Please delete corresponding energy records".

Comment: I want to get a code so that it can be applied to all the contollers.the message should display corresponding table name